# Add ability to cancel flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, retracted-flags

It occasionally happens that a post or comment is flagged in error. Perhaps one's finger slipped and the wrong tiny icon was clicked. Perhaps the text was misread and a subsequent reading makes one wish that it hadn't been flagged. Or perhaps one has finally had some coffee and is better equipped to deal with the world.

In any event, it sure would be nice to remove one's own flags out of the flag queue.

Certainly on Stack Overflow there are just a ton of flags to deal with, and if I can remove one of my own myself I'd reduce that pile ever so slightly. I also really don't want to waste someone else's time when I know that the flag is going to be declined.

The simplest interface I can think of is to simply allow one to click the "active" icon on `stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/{user-id}` to cancel a flag. I'd also think there'd be a "Do you want to cancel this flag?" confirmation, and that the "this user has already flagged this item" bit would still be set to prevent mischief. (In much the same way that you can retract a vote to close, but then you can't vote to close a second time.)

Comment: Completely agree, there are a few feature requests on this on the main meta. These may be ones you wish to support; [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag) or [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: It's actually worse than that, you might also have flagged a post for missing information, which is then added later on, but you have no way of cancelling your flag.

Comment: So we want to undo flags, but we don't want to undo votes?

Comment: It should be exactly the same as up-voting a comment (a comment, not a question or answer). You should be able to flag a chat message, and then un-flag it, but then you can't flag it again.

Comment: Now I have an urge to "accidentally flag." 

@aliteralmind good idea I second this.

Comment: came to Meta to ask exactly the same question and found this one. It was asked almost a year ago, and still no response from moderators on this one. hmm..

Comment: I came here because I raised a flag for a low quality question without considering "on hold" as an option.  I would like to change my flag from low quality to on hold but can't.  This seems like a limitation to an otherwise very free site.

Comment: This totally answers the question as to where the heck is that undo flag button. After rereading my last flagged question I felt that is wasn't as broad as I thought in the first place and now I feel bad for raising this flag. You may probably want to add `cancel/undo` to your question title. As it will be easier to find.

Answer (score 159):

I agree and I'd like to see this. I'm not quite sure why this post isn't receiving attention, because I'd think that, while I don't yet have enough rep to review flags, anything to reduce the massive pile of them would be appreciated. As @h2ooooooo pointed out, if a post is flagged for missing information, there's currently no way to unflag it if that information is added.

Considering the fact that even I, as a relatively new user, have a few flags from months ago that are still `active`, being able to unflag them would make sense: I can't imagine how many active flags more experienced users have, although I guess the ability to close vote reduces flagging activity significantly.

Also, this post has been used as reference for <strike>two</strike> <strike>three</strike> four (and counting) posts marked as duplicates, so I think it deserves a real answer.

Comment: Anecdotal: Of my 556 flags (not incl. spam or comment flags) I have 39 still waiting for review. 11 are within the last week so I'd imagine they're not yet quite lost in the backlog. I just flicked through a few pages and of the first 20 still "active" I'd perhaps retract 2. I do know that I have accidentally flagged at least 2 posts when I didn't mean to either from believing I was in a different tab or because I opened the dialog so I could copy-paste some text from it. Not sure whether they were accepted/rejected though in the end.

Comment: Just to provide some context: I now have 857 flags, of which 91 are waiting for review.

Comment: I accidentally flagged a user who was asking for some help and was going through a tough time. Besides felling terrible, I also realized that the question wasn't deserving of the flag.

Answer (score 46):

Was searching for a way to cancel a flag. Found this feature request.

It turns out that the feature request *has* been implemented, as I just discovered to how to cancel a flag, when I went to flag the same post a second time (in order to ask that the first flag be ignored).

### How to cancel a flag

1. If you flag the post a second time, the "I am flagging to..." dialog shows you which flag you had raised, and the **Flag** button changes to **Retract Flag**.

   [image]
2. If you click on the "Retract Flag" button, your previous flag is cancelled.

   [image]

Your profile's flags page also shows that the flag was self-removed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works for about a month now, here and on Meta Stack Exchange. It will be rolled out later to other site, as can been seen in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/295232).

Comment: Nice! This question didn't get tagged [tag:status-completed], and I hadn't thought to check on MSE. Thanks for the link!

Comment: This seems to be not working for comment flags...

Answer (score 17):

This is completed and live as of August 2016, [see my answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/91) for more details.