# Do moderators see which revision of a question I flagged?

Tags: support

Related: [Add ability to cancel flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252155/754705)

What should I do, if I flag a question as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem", and a minute later, the OP edits his post and now it is 100% clear what he wants? If a moderator sees my flag, will he see a good question, and then some dumb user who flagged it as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem", or will he see that I flagged an old revision that was indeed unclear?

The easist way for me would be if I were able to cancel my flag. Another approach would be if I could somehow "flag" the question as "okay" after it was edited, to make clear that I flagged an old revision and the new revision is okay IMHO.

Or is this not a problem, maybe because reviewers will see that I flagged an old version of the post and they will notice that it has been edited and that it is now okay anyways?

I'm asking because my flag is still "active" and I don't want it to become "accepted" in a few days... What's the correct thing to do in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators - neither those of use with a diamond nor those with > 10K reputation know which version of a post you flagged. All we have to go on is the current state of the post.

If the post has been improved so the flag no longer applies then your flag will most likely be flagged as "invalid". This makes your flag "disputed" so that it's neither a helpful flag nor a declined flag.

This is perfectly normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Well, we don't see flags anymore. Review actions dispute flags, maybe?