# Flagging and changing posts

Tags: discussion, flags

It happened to me a few times now and it starts to bug me: I flag a question as NAA, and after flagging it, it got changed. Obviously the flag is declined or disputed.

Today I flagged this answer as NAA: [SQL sequence not came out with right number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226907/993547). At that point the answer was just (simplified) ([revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24226907/1)):

> Your code works
>
> [THE ORIGNAL CODE]

That doesn't get close to an answer. So I flagged it (after waiting half an hour on improvement).

Positively, the one posting the answer updated after my comment, but the flag was still there. I can't retract my flag, so I had to sit and wait. In the meantime, someone already got the review and agreed with me, but after the change, it was disputed (which was correct at that time).

Still, my flag got disputed, which doesn't show up nice in your flag history, and there must be a lot of people experiencing this same problem.

How to handle such situations. I have seen [discussions on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) about the possibility to retract a flag, but it still isn't there.

Any other ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Possibly related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252155/2982225

Comment: Thanks. I already upvoted that one ;)

Comment: Probably not necessary, but a possible solution if this becomes a problem: When a flagged post is edited, the person posting the flag should get a message notifying them, and an opportunity to retract their flag if the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Or, simpler and more automatic, a declined flag should not be counted if the last edit on the flagged post was after the flag was placed. In that situation, the moderator is not seeing the post as it was when flagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until the ability to retract a flag is implemented, there is absolutely nothing you can do. But it really isn't a major issue, which probably is why there isn't a huge rush to implement such a feature<sup>1</sup>.

- Disputed flags may look "not nice" in your flag history but they are effective neutral.  They don't count against you in your flag score and hence does not impact the flag ban calculation.
- Declined flags do impact the flagging ban calculation, but if it doesn't happen often then it really won't matter.  One or 2 declined flags every once in a while shouldn't matter much, they happen to everyone.

If you find yourself getting a lot more declined flags and pushing the thresholds of the flag ban (>25% for your flags in the last week are declined), then the only option is to reevaluate how you choose to flag (or when you flag).  You could possibly wait longer before raising the flag, but obviously the risk you run there is you forget to go back to the question and flag it.

<sup>1</sup> - obviously canceling flags will help reduce the moderator workload, but may of the flags one would raise in this case, such as "not-an-answer" and "low-quality-questions" do get given to the community via the Low Quality Posts review queue, so they are already offloading the moderators in that respect.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. My declined rate is below 4%, most of them from my first months in SO, so that isn't a problem. It would be useful to have this feature since it lowers the weight on mods too.

Comment: You are right on the flag queues, the comment was more in general.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was actually typing that blurb about the mods at the same time you left your comment so it wasn't directly in response to your comment.  Most of the flags you would raise in these cases, go to the community as well as the mods so if they community handles it before the mod does, it doesn't impact the mods at all.  The only real case where retracting flags would save the mods time is "other" flags.  I agree the ability is needed, but SE obviously feels that it isn't a high priority.