# Dealing with tag-only edit sprees

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today I was perusing the Suggested Edits review queue and came across a good 10 or so review tasks singularly editing [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) into questions already tagged [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). Curious, I visited his [activities page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509121/ben-rhys-lewis?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=2), only to find he had suggested a good 50 or so of just that today, and more in the previous days. I've raised a modflag on one of the approved edits, but it got me thinking. Is there anything else besides a modflag that I can intermittently do to stop stuff like this? If not, is it wise to then go and reject every single one of those you come across? If not, what else can be done?

Update: The user is at it again, this time adding [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) to all questions tagged [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba). The custom moderator flag I raised on friday on this case is still pending.

Review Tasks: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11853863) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11853854) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11853861) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11853656) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11853890)

Update (Tasks): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11883114) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11883112) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11883110) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11883107) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11883102)

Comment: One can argue that this is robo-editing which will prevent said user to look further to see if there is more to edit in there. That basically puts it in the territory of limiting edit suggestion blasting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits

Comment: @Gimby I've since looked through his edit history a bit more and it seems like he has literally hundreds of tag only edits only with those two tags. Hundreds of which have been (robo-) approved. :/

Comment: Good edit - approve, bad - reject. What does any "spree" or anything else BESIDES edit content have to do with reviewing?

Comment: I call them edit nazis. Very often question asked 5 minutes ago is already edited 3 times by 2 different people, and it really is a problem. On the other hand keep in mind you cannot make an edit if you do not change more than x characters (60?), so that is also senseless.

Comment: I also proposed a feature for rate-limiting edit suggestions once: [Do not allow edits on different posts within 5 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154893/do-not-allow-edits-on-different-posts-within-5-minutes) . Nowadays I think 5 minutes is a bit much, but a forced 2 minute delay could significantly impair robo-editors.

Comment: @vove, "it really is a problem"? What problem, exactly?

Comment: [That problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260595/flagging-and-changing-posts), for example and few mores

Answer (score 9):

As long as the edits are good, I don't see the problem.
Just make sure to properly evaluate each suggestion.

Good edits shouldn't be discarded just because a single users makes a lot of the same edits. Edits should be judged on their own quality.

That said, there appears to be a lot of confusion about whether or not edit suggestions like that are acceptable.

Looking through his suggestion history, while the majority of the suggestions are accepted, a lot of them get 2 rejections & 3 accepts.
(His suggestions aren't *just* [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)&[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) additions. He's adding other tags as well)
SO could probably do with some kind of clarification about what constitutes an acceptable edit.

Comment: I stumbled upon exactly this issue. Initially I accepted a couple of those because the description of vba mentions that if the problem is specific to Excel or Word, the relevant tags should **also** added. But I became more uncertain when I noticed it was a spree and I just decided to skip passing any judgement.

Comment: definitely would like to know if tagging vba & ms-word actually improve search results over just word-vba