# Is there a way for me to take back a flag

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269799/pythonic-way-to-extract-specific-values-from-a-dictionary-based-on-a-subset-of-k) on SO yesterday.  It was a bit frustrating because there were some less than nice comments and one of the answers initially was really another not so nice comment.  I tried really hard not to get sucked into the pettiness that I thought was being displayed.  But I was not totally successful.

At some point I wanted to just delete the question.  Because there were two answers at that point I was given the message that I could not delete the question.  Thus I decided to flag it for moderator help.  I did.

One of the answers was deleted and things settled down.  Further a really useful answer was offered.  Thus I think the question (as weak as some might find it) is actually now useful so I wanted to remove my flag but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: If the answer was truly either (A) a comment rather than an answer, or (B) rude and completely unhelpful, or (C) both, then **you should have flagged the answer**, not your question! We don't tolerate either of those things.

Comment: @hichris123: No, but it would have made this redundant

Comment: @hichris123: Yeah that one would be better except someone wasted it my mis-duping _that_ one in the same way you're trying to! Oh wait, it was you. -.-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to revoke a flag, but there has been discussion about this feature's implementation without an official answer: [Add ability to cancel flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you pointing that out

Comment: @AstroCB - To be fair, us janitors can't really do anything about tools. You have to talk to the devs about that. I did take care of the flag in this case and didn't delete the question, though.

Comment: @AstroCB IIUC they are completely revamping the flag system at some point in the near future, so don't assume you've been ignored.  Just that changes in a site of this side are... hard.

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's what I've seen in my short time here...