# Incorrectly flagged a chat comment. Can't unflag it. Please let me

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat

I incorrectly flagged [this comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17936177#17936177) on Python chat, but I can't unflag it. Can we have un-flag option, so that we don't have to clog up moderators' time?

In my opinion, this should be handled the same as up-voting a comment (a comment, not a question or answer). You should be able to flag a chat message, and then un-flag it, but then you can't flag it again.

Comment: Okay, we have [dup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252155/1903116) for this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as that is talking about flags on the main site whereas this is talking about chat-flags.

Comment: That's assuming chat flags are handled differently than flags elsewhere

Comment: Saying it is a dup assumes they are handled the same. :)

Comment: Saying it isn't a dupe is assuming they are handled differently

Comment: @KevinB No, if we don't assume anything the default is not dup.

Comment: uhm... if you don't assume anything, you can't really decide either way. if you don't assume anything, you don't know whether a chat flag is any different from a comment or question flag. \*confused*

Comment: @KevinB Chat has a completely different codebase than the main site.

Comment: Right, but does that mean they go to a completely different flag system than flags elsewhere? not necessarily. I'm not a mod though so i can't really answer that. I would assume that it they did, i can't think of a reason they wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, chat flags go to a different system than flags on the sites do, @KevinB.

Comment: @KevinB bjb is a troll known for inciting pointless semantic arguments.

Comment: How often does it happen that one flags a chat message by accident? It did indeed happen to me, too, but I suppose the number is reasonably low.

Comment: @KevinB If you can't decide either way, you can't say it's a dup.

Comment: Since when are semantics pointless when constructing logical responses?  This site is heavily based off the programming community, which means any advanced user here should understand the semantics of logic.  Kevin B's comment based on the inverse of neuronet's comment clearly oversimplifies the matter.  He is excluding the fact that questions in an unknown dup state should clearly be unchecked, because being unchecked also includes an unkown state of dupness. This should be obvious by the fact that questions always exist in a non-dup state for some amount of time before being marked as a dup.