# Do moderators look at the revision history before declining a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389264/) as offensive since it contained swear words in the output log. Anyway my flag got rejected with

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

anyway the words are clearly visible in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25389264/revisions): the user removed the words before the moderator took a look at the post.

Do moderators check the edit history and/or have something like a "snapshot" of the post to justify flags that were raised at that time?

Comment: Why should they? The post was edited, mission accomplished, right?

Comment: I agree but the flag count is public and I suppose also the number of declined flags. It just doesn't feel right to have a "declined flag" just because a user played it dirty by editing the post JIT

Comment: @MartijnPieters except that the flag reporting a real problem is declined ([“slap on the wrist”](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/) and such...)

Comment: @MarcoA.: actually, your flag count is *not* public. I cannot see yours, you cannot see mine. The only time that information is exposed beyond moderators is when you stand for elections.

Comment: @gnat: Right, I wasn't aware of that guideline! Interesting; I don't mind the occasional 'declined' myself.

Comment: @Marco A.: If it helps, the declined flag count is only visible to yourself and us. It is not visible publicly. But I agree, it sucks to not be able to rescind your flag once it is made obsolete before it's handled. There are more than a few [discussions around this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags), however they don't seem to have been addressed yet.

Comment: shouldn't the flag be dismissed instead of declined though @BoltClock?

Comment: Declined is one of the outcomes of dismissing a flag, @mehow. A flag is either helpful or declined (unhelpful). It's possible for a moderator to remove spam/offensive flags through other means, though, assuming the flag had any basis in the first place.

Comment: I hope they look at the revision history before **accepting** a flag. Oterwise, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work , someone might receive a -100 for edits that others have made to his post...

Comment: -1 it's utterly absurd even downvoting for file/variable names, not to mention flagging as offensive. Offensive flag should be reserved for answers suggesting to use Visual C++ for Linux users etc.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt I definitely wouldn't flag 'offensive' someone suggesting to use visual c++ on linux.. perhaps 'ignorant' but not offensive. Let's not start a religious war :)

Comment: @MarcoA. it was an irony :D

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt I failed to catch it, sorry :( That means I'm tired.. and even before starting to work!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, if there's any confusion about why a post was flagged, we will look at the revision history to see if the problem was already resolved.

The problem is that you used an **offensive** flag because a user had the word "shit" in their code and forgot to remove it before posting. That flag carries a 100 reputation penalty, so it's quite a bit of overkill for this offense. Better to just edit out the curse word, and save the offensive flags for posts that need to be nuked from orbit immediately.

Comment: Good point. Generally you should only use the "offensive" flag if the post was written with an intent to offend. If the content can be sterilized by editing out the offensive words, then the *post* is not offensive *per se*.

Comment: Understood, I looked for a reason on the list of flags but couldn't find one that suited. I'll keep the offensive flag for **very serious issues** from now on.

Comment: "That flag carries a 100 reputation penalty" -- I had no idea. I'm not easily offended so I don't think I've ever used it, but it could be more clear in the UI that this should be reserved for egregious infractions and that it is likely to be declined unless it is really bad.

Comment: @Marco I think Bill's point is more so that, as an experienced user with 10k+ reputation, you should just edit out minor infractions yourself. It is just about as easy as going through the steps to flag, and it *fixes the problem immediately*. The only time you need to get a moderator involved with an offensive flag is when you want the post deleted outright (which you can't do yourself).

Comment: "That flag carries a 100 reputation penalty" 　What does this imply? The one who raised the flag gets a 100rep deduction or the one who use  offensive words?

Comment: @LazyNinja The one who used the offensive words of course (only if the flag is accepted).

Comment: @Nateowami thank you! Had no idea.

Answer (score 17):

If we can't figure out why you've flagged something and see it's been edited, then yes we will check the revision history to see what you were talking about.

In this particular case, your offensive flag was invalid. You could have easily just edited those words out and the post would have been perfectly fine. Offensive flags can have severe penalties, and should only ever be used for severely offensive/abusive content that needs to be deleted immediately. This question clearly doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: Maybe I'm being unsympathetic, but Mods should not have to grind through history. The flag should clearly and succinctly state the problem, and the Mods should be able to quickly verify it. Perhaps the problem is: Flags need another state of "no action" that does not penalize the person who performs the flag. That way, Mods don't have to wade through history and flaggers are not penalized when a post changes.

Comment: @jww When you're wielding a 100 rep hammer, a short amount of time to review history doesn't seem unreasonable. WRT other flags, I'd agree with you (but that could be assisted by the site making a note of/diffing the flagged revision?)