# Why Is a Flag Declined Instead of "Aged Away" If It Took Too Long For a Moderator to Review?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, etiquette

In order to protect the innocent, and/or guilty, I will describe only the higher level elements of this. I saw an answer that I flagged the content of because, one paragraph suggested a potential solution, this part seemed OK to mean (this part was not the purpose of my flag, to note the line with the issue the unnecessary content, paraphrase: "I don't have time to answer this question...may if someone upvotes". It took over several hours before my flag was actually reviewed, and then the individual who, finally, reviewed my flag would have seen the related line(s) removed (whether revision history was checked or not, is not clear from the decline response):

"declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

**My goal/purpose here**: Isn't there an option for a moderator to **not** have to decline, when my flag, which seemed to me (open to constructive feedback), was fully justified based on the comment content at the time the flag was created; however, by the time my flag was reviewed, the purpose for my flag was fixed by this individual. To be clear, I understand moderators can be busy; however, I don't believe a valid flag, at the time it was flagged, should be entered into declined state simply because it took some additional time for a moderator to review. I have at least one flag that aged away (whether valid now or not, I don't mind overlooking).

Lastly, in hindsight, if I knew it would take several hours for a moderator to review the content that didn't need to be in the answer, I would have just edited it myself. I also did not edit it myself as my goal wasn't get points from making that change so I chose the flag option, at the time.

Related Post(s):

- [Do moderators look at the revision history before declining a flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269225/do-moderators-look-at-the-revision-history-before-declining-a-flag)

Comment: What made you sure your flag _needs moderator invention_? Clarify please, technical issues in an answer aren't a valid reason for flagging it. Down/close vote and move on instead.

Comment: _"I would have just edited it myself."_ Which is why even if a mod had seen it in five minutes it would have likely been declined. _You do not need a mod to perform an edit._ A flag is the wrong course of action for content you can deal with yourself. Think of moderators as human exception handlers- Don't call them for something that isn't exceptional.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a technical issue in the answer itself, it was a, paraphrase: "here is a suggested component available in language X that may help...gimmie a freebie vote up and maybe I'll provide code as I don't have time to do so now". To be fair to the related individual, code was added sometime later. My primary issue for the flag was the "gimmie a vote up"

Comment: @localhost Then you should have edited that out, not flagged the post for a moderator to edit it out.

Comment: @Kendra maybe, except I've been having recent experience, in SO, where even valid edits I make have been thrown out wholesale where it seems the edit itself was not even reviewed before being thrown out.

Comment: @localhost You didn't suggest an edit.  You flagged the post to say that someone else should go edit it.  Had you actually suggested an edit it may well have been approved.

Comment: @localhost well, I've just had a quick look at the flag you've mentioned. It's not clear what you're trying to say or what the issue you're concerned about is. Even after re-reading it, I still can't make out more than "this could use an edit" - which isn't what mods need to be made aware...

Comment: @localhost If the message you're getting on those edits is "conflicts with a subsequent edit" then that is by-design. If a user with full editing rights edits at the same time as you, their edit will knock yours out of the queue as theirs doesn't have to be reviewed. If you don't want to edit, that's fine, but as Servy said in their answer you should not flag for that. Someone with editing rights can come and do it if you (and other low-rep users) won't.

Comment: @Kendra That wasn't the issue in this case, there was not an edits conflict.

Comment: So we've established as you've said you flagged and didn't edit- Which we are saying is wrong. Getting your edits knocked out of the queue on other posts is no reason to flag moderator for an edit on the one you did. Either edit or don't, flagging is not the right answer in the case described.

Comment: @JonClements My flag clearly contained this line, after first stating it was salvageable: "clearly asking for one or more "freebie" upvotes without doing much more work..." I'm not sure why you are not seeing, at the very beginning I state my concern in that case.

Comment: @localhost Even then the action to be taken to address that concern is to edit it out the post - you don't require a moderator for that. Since the OP even had a smiley after the "please up vote" me, it's not entirely sure they're that serious about it anyway (but yes, no reason for it to be in the answer - so editing it out is appropriate action). If they were spamming posts with "plz upvote k thx" - then that's something that warrants moderator attention.

Answer (score 18):

Moderators are not there to edit irrelevant information out of posts because you can't be bothered to do it yourself.  Either edit the post yourself to fix the problems or don't and move on; either is fine, but flagging is not.  Moderators exist to handle serious problems that the community is incapable of handling on its own.  This in no way qualifies.

Comment: What if it's a serious one-character typo and the flagger can't edit (or even comment) yet?

Comment: @Jan They should poke grammar owls in chat to get it fixed.

Comment: @JanDvorak: then the flagger moves on, if it really is serious *and* visible (e.g. people actually visit and look at that post) a 2k user will edit it soon enough.

Comment: ... maybe I should just bolden three random words instead.