# In what cases can the "offensive" flag be used?

Tags: support, flags, offensive-flag

I recently saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32857540/8) where the OP had edited it to be offensive, & I flagged it. The flag was declined as `declined - Rolling back the edit was clearly the correct thing to do, not flag.`:

[image]

I was going to ask why it was declined (the content was offensive, it should've merited the [offensive] flag), but then I came across [Bill the Lizard's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269228/2422013) on [Do moderators look at the revision history before declining a flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269225/do-moderators-look-at-the-revision-history-before-declining-a-flag), which states:

> The problem is that you used an offensive flag because a user had the
>   word "sh-t" in their code and forgot to remove it before posting. That
>   flag carries a 100 reputation penalty, so it's quite a bit of overkill
>   for this offense. Better to just edit out the curse word, and save the
>   offensive flags for posts that need to be nuked from orbit
>   immediately.

It was a similar situation here, but the user purposely edited their question to add the offensive content. I see why the [offensive] flag was invalid as it could've (and was) edited out by another user.

---

However, that *does* lead to the question: doesn't this mean that *every* [offensive] flag is invalid? This is because *every post* can be edited to remove the offensive content (the exception being locked posts, of which *it is not possible to flag these posts*).

I'm slightly confused; what content actually merits the use of the [offensive] flag?

I did bring up the topic on one of the chat rooms (I tried to find the messages, but I'm unable to find them- will update this if I manage to find them) and one user said something along the lines of:

> I'd only flag as [offensive] if the user does it again.

Is this (repeat posts/edits/whatever with offensive language) use case what the "offensive" flag is for?

Please could this be clarified?

Comment: Without searching the metas for precedents, my gut feeling is that offensive flags are better suited for offensiveness directed at a person or a group of persons, rather than non-directed swearing. (I don't know if that applies to your flag, though.)

Comment: @duplode So not [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32857540/8) then?

Comment: Yup, I suspect this doesn't cross the threshold for flagging.

Comment: fyi, tag removal requests here on Meta always take the form of "Remove [unhelpful-tag] etc". Even if "[offensive]" isn't technically the syntax used to represent a tag in SO's markdown, to Meta users, that's exactly what it represents. I removed the square brackets from your title because of their association with discussing tags here on Meta, and I personally think that using the quotation marks instead makes it clearer what your question is about (i.e. not talking about the [offensive] tag itself, but the "offensive" flag).

Comment: [This comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag#comment251268_306821) from Brad Larson explicitly says that if a user defaces his own post in an offensive way then a custom flag "may be warranted". Doesn't say anything about "offensive" flag though, but I suppose this falls in the same bucket... The user clearly was offensive before in his edits on the same question.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the 100 rep penalty.

Comment: some (a lot of?) people don't find swearing offensive. that's a pretty good reason right there.

Comment: I have to say I'm glad that he ragequit.The edit history for that question - OP: Write this code for me. Us: closed as too broad. OP: you guys suck, no it's not. Us: Saying so doesn't make it true. OP: [Screw you guys, I'm going home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyltK6pmJGg)

Comment: Huh, I had no idea the flag came with such a hefty penalty. I will think thrice before using it from now on.

Comment: Regarding your assertion that all offensive posts can be edited, a couple of days ago I flagged an answer as offensive, as the general gist of it was "Group X of people are clueless, if they had a clue they would not be in group X, what x (belonging to group X) said is meaningless rubbish". Now, IMO it's not offensive because of strong language, but because of the actual content, and it cannot be edited away (and it was not an NAA, because the question was "x said ..., is it correct?").

Comment: @RealSkeptic That wasn't my deduction, it was of the moderator's in the post I linked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, you are quite right that the user was intentionally offensive.
And the post, as you flagged it, was offensive too.

But, as the moderator said:

> Rolling back the edit was clearly the right thing to do, not flag

Well, you *could* use a custom flag to ask a moderator to investigate if you saw a pattern and thought there was more you couldn't deal with ("poster is doing a rage-quit. I rolled back what he defaced, please take a look whether he nuked other posts.")

The offensive-flag is patently inappropriate because only that edit was offensive, not the whole post, and a validated offensive-flag destroys the post.

Even if the first revision *contains* something offensive, *sometimes* it can be salvaged by editing.

Comment: So: `Only use the [offensive] flag if the **whole post** is offensive`?

Comment: Yes... if you can easily save the post with more benign means, that's to be preferred. Especially as nuking the question also removes any answers.

Comment: I don't really see how this "saves" the post as there are no relevant answers and the question is closed to answers.

Comment: So in theory there is no limit to how extreme and offensive things a question could contain without meriting a flag as opposed to an edit, as long as the post also contains a valid question? (This is not an attempt at an argument, just asking to get clarity.)

Comment: @Anders: It depends on whether there's something potentially worth saving, how intentional/blatant/bad the offense is, whether it was there from the beginning, and how difficult it is to correct. In the end it needs your personal considered judgement how best to proceed for the good of the site, or it would simply be automated.

Comment: You can totally kill flies with a flamethrower, but... Usually you want to go with a less powerful tool.

Comment: What's worse, not liking someone's speech or sex slavery? Because I don't see any of you working to end that lol

Comment: What about paper cuts? Where do those line up on this?

Comment: So if I want to live stream me *******ing a ******* in the ******* whilst simultaneously *******ing a raging ******* in both *********es it is ok to post about it as long as the question relates to the streaming and not the ********ing? Even if I accidentally the whole bottle?

Answer (score 16):

I'd say this was a borderline case.  Personally, I think your flag was reasonable under the circumstances, but I can also understand why the mod who handled it chose to decline it.

On one hand, if the content you flagged had been the *only* version of the question, an "offensive" flag would've been 100% justified.  Not only was the content blatantly offensive, but, more importantly, it was also blatantly unsalvageable — simply editing out the offensive parts would've left us with a non-question.

On the other hand, in this case, there *was* something that you could've done to fix the question — namely reverting it to an earlier version that *was* a valid, non-offensive question.  In general, if a valid post has been vandalized (whether by its author or by someone else), it should be reverted, not flagged.  (If ♦ mod intervention is needed, a custom flag explaining the situation may be appropriate.)

On the third hand, even before it was vandalized by its author, the question had been closed and heavily downvoted.  Thus, arguably, it was still a bad question, and reverting only made it slightly less bad.  Also, the OP had vandalized the question, and been reverted, several times before.  Thus, one could argue that deleting the question and slapping the OP with the 100 rep penalty would, in fact, have been appropriate.

On the fourth hand (geez, what am I, an octopus?), one could argue about whether the original question *really* deserved to be closed (as reflected by the fact that it has since been reopened).  At least, it probably should've been reopened after the OP clarified it.  Clearly, the OP didn't handle the situation well, but arguably there was a systemic failure on SO's part as well.

On the fifth hand (I really should come up with a better simile here), it's *still* kind of a "gimme teh codez" question.  The OP's "effort so far" consists of downloading a script off the Internet that they, by their own admission, don't understand.  Arguably, it's still off topic for SO.  (It could, perhaps, be a valid question on [SU](http://superuser.com).)

So, [on the gripping hand](http://catb.org/jargon/html/O/on-the-gripping-hand.html)... *meh*.  It's a borderline off-topic question, now reopened but still at -10 score.  It's got one answer, which won't do the OP any good because it's in PHP and they don't have PHP installed.  Unless it's rescued by the meta effect, it'll probably remain that way until the Roomba eventually deletes it.  And also, even if the OP did have some legitimate reasons to be annoyed, their temperament and attitude still seems rather poorly suited for SO.

So, in the end, whether or not your "offensive" flag was valid or useful depends on how deep one is willing to dig into this borderline case before making a decision one way or the other.  And in any case, whether or not it was accepted probably won't make much long-term difference, neither for the question nor for the OP.

Most likely, the *best* option would've been to just revert (to fix the immediate issue) and raise a custom ♦ mod flag, and let the mods deal with the bigger issue as they see fit.  That's why we have them.