# Why is this question heavily downvoted but not closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, downvote-reason

I was just curious to know why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068763) would receive bundles of downvotes.

But the most amazing thing is, why is this question not closed currently?

Are downvotes independent of close votes?

Comment: I'm more amazed that of 58 (current count) downvoters not one took the time / had the guts to add an explanation why :/ Now you have a warped view of a heavily downvoted question with a decently upvoted answer. Hard to understand what train of thought goes into the community moderation of that question.

Comment: I think some of the downvotes are due to the line of code `printf("Go f**k a donkey, faggot.");`, found in [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21068763/1)

Comment: Oops somebody may dig into your history to vote, so think twice before submission, lesson learned :)

Comment: @Gimby - I'm sure that a mod purged comments.

Comment: Well that's sad. Here are a lot of "engineers" that's why. Any way strange things happens in here

Comment: @user000001 I know you are just quoting text from a revision, but I don't think you should re-post offensive language like that.

Comment: It's not a polite phrase in the original revision, and I wouldn't address my users like that, but I guess it was just a testversion of the message "Invalid input, try again". I don't think anyone but donkeys and [Harley riders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGyKBFCd_u4) should be offended by it.

Comment: Oh c'mon now... why bring HOGs into this thread!

Comment: I just upvoted so the number of votes is offensive as well. Don't know how long that would last.

Comment: Answer it and get the [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) gold badge

Comment: @theB poo on me for not thinking of that. Pessimism is a disease I need to cure someday soon.

Comment: Funny that the amount of negative votes prompted this question, which, because of its upvotes, is "featured", and now I've been offended. :)

Comment: Sometimes I see a heavily upvoted question and wonder, "Why is this not closed?"

Comment: @user000001 - Well that just makes me wonder why it didn't get flagged for being offensive.

Comment: The hog is at minus three figures now..

Comment: @BSMP Presumably because the post was deemed salvageable. Cf. [In what cases can the “offensive” flag be used?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307383/2751851)

Comment: Oh sorry for having strong meta effect accidently :( Originally I was just thought the post was mislooked for closing and then people just start downvote-bullying, not realize the down-votes are for the question history

Comment: lol, did the user get suspended because of this post or was all the rep they had obliterated by the meta effect?

Comment: Apologise again:( I don't know editing would push the topic up :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, downvotes formally are independent of close votes.

Downvote - no research/not useful (clearly the case of lack of any research shown in the post).

Close - all sorts of off-topic (clearly not the case), or duplicate (probably the case, but one need to spend effort to find a good matching question - so less likely to happen), or lack of details like sample/expected behavior (again not the case).

Indeed usually downvoted questions also hit some close reasons like "no code shown" / "not clear". But sometimes they just useful and on-topic, just without any way to improve into good question.

Comment: The question title has nothing to do with the actual question (which makes it less likely to be found) so that's one thing that could be improved.

Comment: In particular, a closed question can still be "good" in the sense of showing great research, being technically interesting, or anything else. It's just not necessarily in the right place. Close+upvote is a rare combination, but it does happen.

Comment: @Leushenko upvote+close happens regularly on decent or even good questions that were once on-topic, but are not anymore due to changes in policy/rules and hence get closed

Comment: @Leushenko [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696168/curious-about-the-implementation-of-caseinsensitivecomparator/31696231#31696231) is an example.