# Offensive flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags

I was reviewing my flags a few hours ago. I noticed that one of the posts I flagged as an offensive was declined. I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146285/my-instructor-is-an-asshole) question which was deleted later. It contained a bad word in it.

This is what it looks in my flag list,

[image]

*Why did a moderator not find any evidence to support this flag?*

Comment: My guess would be that a mod deleted the question just by stumbling over it without coming from the flag queue. Another mod then saw your flag in the queue and saw that it already was deleted and declined your flag.

Comment: @Rizier123 Looks like the question merited deletion because it's a bad quesiton, not because it's offensive, hence why the flag was declined.

Comment: @Servy I think OP here flagged it as rude based on the title. And I think the title can be seen as offensive.

Comment: @Rizier123 And that can be fixed with a simple edit, which the OP could have done on his own.  The question wouldn't merit deletion on those grounds.

Comment: @Servy Then why is it possible to raise such a flag in the first place, if it can/should be solved by editing?

Comment: @Stijn Why is it possible to flag posts for reasons that don't apply to those posts?  Because there's no way for the system to know whether or not those flags apply to the post in question.  If the software itself could always know whether any given flag applied, then you'd have a Nobel Prize worthy AI on your hands.

Comment: @Servy But we as users can always edit posts, be it directly or via a suggested edit. What is the purpose of the flag then?

Comment: @Stijn For problems that can't be fixed by editing.

Comment: @Stijn I disagree. Editing those post which can be improved is fine but not those which contains offensive content. It would be like hiding sins of others. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Servy Please give an example of a problem that can't be fixed by editing and instead one should use the 'offensive' flag.

Comment: @Stijn I can give an example; ones that are repeats of the same 3 bad words for the entirety of the post.

Comment: @Laurel We can vote to close those, and later on vote to delete them. No moderator involvement necessary. (I'm just applying the same logic here as to why we apparently shouldn't use the flag and edit instead)

Comment: @Stijn A post that is nothing *but* insults would merit flagging, as there would be nothing there if you removed the offensive content.  This post merely needs to remove one word to not be offensive.

Comment: @Stijn The post *was* closed by the community, and attracted 2 delete votes.  The 3rd delete vote was from a moderator, but as that moderator has enough rep to delete questions, they didn't need their moderator powers to delete the post.  In effect, the question *was* handled by the community.

Comment: @Stijn You can take the same action on spam. Unfortunately, VTC is the wrong action in either that case or when the post is nothing but bad words.

Comment: @Laurel The spam flag is a special case because it trains the spam filter. AFAIK there's no "offensive post" filter. Anyway, I feel like this discussion is leading nowhere. I'll post a new question on the topic perhaps.

Comment: @Laurel No, that's a radically different situation.  This post merits deletion on just being a bad question, but it wouldn't merit deletion just because it contains one offensive word.  If the quesiton was actually an appropriate question it could simply have been edited to remove that one word.  The post in this case merited closure and deletion because of the quality of the programming question being asked.  If the post was nothing but this author insulting his teacher, without even being a programming question, then that would be different.

Comment: @Servy I guess I wasn't too clear there; edited my comment. We're on the same page.

Comment: @Stijn: the offensive flag is treated the same as the spam flag. Trolling, flaming and spamming are different aspects of the same phenomenon, inappropriate content on the site.

Comment: @Servy "A post that is nothing but insults would merit flagging" why? It can be taken care of by the community by deleting the post.

Comment: @Stijn The offensive flag will allow it to be deleted more quickly in such a case.

Comment: @Servy That was the kind of answer I was looking for :) Sorry for being such a nuicance, but sometimes I have the feeling that the moderator team is intentionally vague on flag usage.

Comment: Just FYI: Stack Overflow sees more flags in half a day than you've raised in your entire time on the site. Mods are usually happy to explain why something was done, but expecting them to remember after 4 months is pretty crazy. If you're gonna ask, ask promptly. Otherwise, don't worry about it.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree. I do apologies for asking this after 4 months. I'm sure I would have asked this before if I had noticed. I'll spend some more time on taking a bird's eye view on the flag results. *Otherwise, don't worry about it.*  My mind don't allow me to do that ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I probably misclicked. If so, my apologies. Or not, and I expected you to have edited the post.

Not that I can *remember* what happened, seeing as this was several months ago.

Comment: Can you and the rest of the moderator team come up with clear guidance and post it in the form of an official answer at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307383/in-what-cases-can-the-offensive-flag-be-used ? Making the distinction between questions, answers, flags, severity, amount, etc.

Comment: *I expected you to have edited the post.* My hand stops me from clicking edit link when I see something offensive in the post. But yes, I will surely edit post if I think it can be improved.

Comment: @Stijn: Ask the question: does this need a moderator to correct or can the community do something about it? How urgent is it that something is done?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The thing is, right now I'm failing to come up with a case that is only possible to be solved by moderator intervention. And clearly I'm not the only person who has trouble with this, as indicated by the votes on the linked question.

Comment: @Stijn You were given examples in the comments above, along with fairly straightforward guidance, both there, and here, by Martjin.  If you can fix the problem on your own, simply do so, if there's nothing you can do to address the problem, *then* you flag for moderator attention.  Simple enough.

Comment: @Stijn: flagging as offensive carries a severe penalty if enough such votes accrue (guaranteed if a moderator flags as such); the account is penalised 100 points and the anti-spam system is primed with their account. There was a question here, a terrible one, but without the question title that's all that remains. Today, I'd probably just clear the flags (mark as disputed) and edit the post.