# Declined flag for edited post

Tags: support, declined-flags, abuse

I have a recent declined rude/abusive flag on Stack Overflow where apparently the post was edited into shape from underneath.  Is there any way to get the declined status cleaned up in this scenario?  This post was [reported by Smoke Detector](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/84492) so I'm probably not the only one with a declined flag here.

I flagged revision https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46191299/4 but the answer was later rolled back and subsequently edited.  Curiously, the edit was apparently submitted by someone who posted a *different* answer and probably wanted to vandalize *that* but clicked the wrong link ...

Comment: It wasn't even the OP that vandalised. I wonder why Gunther made that edit.

Comment: Like I speculate in the second paragraph, we think he *wanted* to vandalize his own answer, but misclicked.

Comment: At any rate, vandalism like this should be rolled back. It did not need summary execution.

Comment: I guess then possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307383/in-what-cases-can-the-offensive-flag-be-used

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was very obviously a mistake on the part of the user who "vandalized" it, and he quickly corrected his mistake (as did others, who eagerly rolled back his changes, leading to a confusing collision that ultimately resolved itself *within 3 minutes*).

There was absolutely no need for a "rude/abusive" flag on that post. Flagging with the aid of a bot doesn't excuse you from the need to use your brain and pay attention when making decisions about which flags to raise.

The "declined" status doesn't need to be "cleaned up". The flag was correctly declined.

Answer (score 6):

The post in question was not vandalised by the OP but by a high-rep user, one with editing privileges.

Had your rude/abusive flag been accepted the OP would have been penalised. That's not appropriate in this case as he didn't do anything wrong.

Rollback would have been the most appropriate initial action, which was tried. When that failed, a custom flag explaining the issue would have allowed moderators to step in and temporarily lock the post or suspend the user vandalising the post.

Comment: I accepted your answer at first and in some ways like it better, but I'll change the accept to Cody's mainly just to signal that I don't disagree with his somewhat more harsh characterization of the situation. Thanks to both of you for your quick responses.