# What is the difference between declined, disputed and aged away?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, flag-history

I am not able to understand the flagging history.

So when I flag a post like `Very low Quality` and it is declined like `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it` does the moderator looked at the non-edited post which was flagged or does the moderator look at the edited one and assume that the post was of good quality.

who is disputing the flag post and how?

I read about [Why were my older close flags “aged away”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away) but still not clear the concept of Aged-Away.

I understand Helpful.

But what is the difference between declined, disputed and aged away?

It would be really helpful if you can also point (tips) me how to get most of your flags **helpful**.

Comment: see also: [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Bill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269228/), a distinguished former moderator, diamond mods will check revision history if there's any real doubt about a flag's merit before declining. General LQP reviewers may or may not, but *will* see any comments you leave (and can't leave that exact sort of decline message anyway).

Flags that are disputed had enough of a consensus to be sure that the (ordinary, non-diamond) reviewers weren't sure whether the flag was warranted.

Flags that age away did not have enough of a consensus to be sure of anything at all; there just weren't enough reviewers that saw the post and didn't Skip.

In general, helpful flags come from being precise, accurate, and explaining any tricky judgement calls or subtle points you feel necessary in comments (for ordinary reviewers) or custom flag text (for diamonds). There are a few odd quirks of flagging that can only really be discerned by spending time poking through Meta for past discussions; most of them have to do with which answers to delete as NAA.

If you're reasonably careful, you should have very few declined flags, say <2%. It's nice to keep disputed flags to a minimum, but there's really nothing you can do about aged-away flags except only flagging the most flagrant questions to close, or just ignoring close flags entirely. (Much the same applies to disputed flags if you're flagging a lot from Triage, unfortunately.)