# How to "un-decline" a flag raised for an answer edited afterwards?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged the following "answer" as "not an answer":

> +1
>
> Would like to do the same thing
>
> Dis you find a solution?

which IMHO is perfectly fine to flag. 
Afterwards the post was edited and my flag declined. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49658139/revisions) is the full edit history. The reason for the flag was:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I understand why the reviewer declined my flag (the edit transformed the answer into an actual one, which I would have not flagged in the first place).

What can I do to reverse or at least have this flag discussed? At this point I won't flag anything else and would discourage everybody to do it, since you can be penalized for absolutely no fault of your own...

I know that 1 declined flag is not a problem, but if the process is not deterministic and there is no way to "un-decline" a supposedly wrongly declined flag, who can guarantee your work won't be wasted?

Comment: I think [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269225/do-moderators-look-at-the-revision-history-before-declining-a-flag) is roughly the same.

Comment: @AndréKool it's similar, but the issue is different. I had no way to edit the answer to make it acceptable rather than flag it, as it is per your link. It was not an answer at all...

Comment: Plus, my question is: how to correct this problem? The other one just asks if revision history is available to reviewers.

Comment: Yup, thats why I just linked it and not marked it a duplicate.

Comment: I think this is the source of the problem and its maybe a good idea to fix that so this doesnt happen again.

Comment: obviously I don't review the NAA flags nor have ever done, but I think when reviewing the posts they see the comments too which is why when I see an NAA I flag and leave a comment to the answerer saying that its not an answer etc. which if is seen by the people reviewing would prompt them to look at the revision history which would've prevented your declined flag and would've been marked as helpful/disputed

Comment: @WhatsThePoint thanks for your suggestion, actually it might increase the chances of a correct flag evaluation.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint although it makes it sound like it's my fault, which I'm not sure it is. Am I responsible if a reviewer skips revision history when considering my flag? Shouldn't there be a way to "repair" this kind of problem?

Comment: @FrancescoB. as someone who spends a lot of time reviewing I (and many others) keep our most commonly used comments in a text file (or other means depending on your preference) to speed up reviewing

Comment: @FrancescoB. no its not your fault but the moderator queue is always in the thousands due to high traffic this site gets, so moderators don't tend to take more time than needed to review every single flag they try to go through as quick as they can, so anyway to make it easier for them is preferred. and no the flag cannot be undeclined, once its been marked as helpful/disputed/declined it is "locked in" that way, for this situation just grit your teeth and take this one on the chin and mark it as experience

Comment: [Here is an answer from a mod](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317406/4916627) on a simular question.

Comment: @AndréKool yes, thank you, that's it. 2 years later I guess there's still no change in the way those flags are handled.

Comment: Looks like making it obvious a post has been edited after a flag was raised needs to be a feature request.

Comment: Maybe a big "THIS POST HAS BEEN EDITED SINCE THE FLAG WAS RAISED" banner at the top of the review page would work?