# Why were my older close flags "aged away"?

Tags: support, flags

I have raised 373 flags .

> 240 deemed helpful .
>
> 7 declined .
>
> 5 disputed.
>
> 1 commented flag declined.

Before few hours ago there were 115 flags for review.

But **now there are only 49 flags for review**, along with the note that "older flags were not recorded helpful/declined".

Are the other flags I raised going to waste? I am very sad to hear that.

Comment: related: [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as “aged away” by the system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204327/165773)

Comment: I'm with you Don; it feels like such a waste when certain flags will never be reviewed. I have stopped raising certain flag types because I know they will stay pending and nobody will take action. Specifically I no longer raise migration flags. I'm also on the verge of not raising off-topic flags anymore. The side effect is that I now often leave bad content on this site because I have no action to take beyond a downvote and/or a comment.

Comment: @JoelC Migration flags are handled by moderators, who do their best and usually get to such flags within a week. Off-topic flags go to the Close Votes review queue, and, [well...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue)

Comment: Just because a flag is not marked as "processed" by a moderator does not mean it was not considered.    If a moderator can not decide on a flag, it gets left in the queue so other moderators can look at it.   Sometime a moderator will agree with a flag, but then not have time to sort it out, and decide the issue is less important then other flags, so once again leaving the flag in the queue.

Comment: The message you call out about "older flags" is not actually related; it's a note that *a very long time ago, the disposition of flags wasn't recorded*. Mods would process them and mark them done, but it wasn't recorded whether they were helpful or declined.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Your flags were not a waste, Don.

The majority of your flags have been clearly helpful; of the rest, they caused the questions flagged to be put up for review, but some portion were simply not seen as critical enough to warrant action by the rest of the community.

That doesn't necessarily mean they were wrong, just that there were other priorities. The recent change that marks them as "aged" means they won't sit forever in limbo - you now **know** they haven't been acted on, and are free to take alternate action (voting, editing, re-flagging) if you see it as necessary to maintain the quality of the site.

In some cases, the flagged posts may still warrant closure; in others, the post may have been edited to correct outstanding issues. In many cases, it may be that the problems with the question were not so severe that it required closure - if you flagged due to observing a lack of research or effort on the part of the asker, you'd be better off downvoting instead.

Regardless, I want to thank you for taking time to flag posts you've found problematic - it's the combined efforts of everyone like yourself, working together, that keeps Stack Overflow working day after day.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer .I will continue my active presence in SO as always.

Comment: [Shog9, a little over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209640/262399): "Just aging them away doesn't fix this; that just converts an effectively useless flag into one bearing a great big system-applied "YOU WASTED YOUR TIME" stamp."

Comment: Yeah, figured that'd come back & bite me @Jeffrey! As much as I don't like the message this sends to flaggers, letting these sit forever in limbo was becoming a bigger problem - [folks had become accustom to seeing insane numbers of flags awaiting review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags/260587#260587). We did implement some of the other changes I outlined there, but for the stuff that still falls through the cracks it's just not fair to leave them forever waiting.

Comment: Well, I'm happy to see my 16 old flags gone (the oldest going back to June 2013). While they were still there, I could do nothing further (made a couple of largely fruitless attempts in MSO questions). Now I can actually vote to close rather than flagging. Thanks. I felt my time was wasted whilst nothing was done. Now I get another shot. I've been hoping this would happen some time...

Comment: If you have "just" 16 flags it is under some circumstances okay, but loosing about 100 flags is real kind of wasting time. I mean you take your time to look at the post consider what should be the right action and bumm everything gots lost. I fully support @JeffreyBosboom .

Comment: @CSchulz If I had 100 flags, or one, that nothing was going to happen to, I'd be happy for them to disappear. The original figure outstanding prior to the "resolution" of the Close Vote Queue was 36. Once those 20 had gone, the others just became an annoying fester. 16 pieces of rubbish but in low-volume tags where, presumably, the lack of worth of the questions could not be readily recognised. Yays. I can now have another go at them. I don't see the point of keeping 100 flags if *nothing* is going to happen to them and there *nothing* (that I know of) that I can do to remove the rubbish.

Comment: @Shog9 Unfortunately, when going back to re-flag, the valid reason I picked before is now unselectable and is appended with "you have already raised this type of flag". Now a question that maybe should be removed cannot be removed. i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988202/camera-shake-using-mathf-perlinnoise

Comment: You have to wait 14 days after the flag ages away, although there may be something odd happening with this specific flag, @user3071284.

Comment: @Shog9 It was 18 days ago, though it was still grayed out. Anyhow, thanks for putting it on hold.

Comment: 14 days *after it ages*, @user3071284

Answer (score 12):

At least, once one reaches 3k rep, one should go through all own flags waiting for review and vote on them to beat the fading away effect.

Below 3K rep, as the system currently is, a certain part (rough estimation 10-30%) of the flags will never get reviewed. You have to make the decision if under that circumstances it is still worth flagging. One could say that even with some waste there is still a positive effect. And anyway one always has to take into account limited personal ressources - so a 100% instantaneous reviewing rate is not achievable. If the flags stay but get not reviewed, nothing is gained.

If SO gets more flags than can be handled by the reviewers than certainly this hints at another problem somewhere. There may not be enough active reviewers and voters and maybe also moderators. It's voluntary work after all.

Finally a slightly alternative point of view is statistics. By fading away you kind of introduce noise reduction in the flags. Flags would then be seen as noisy, weak signal - and only if they are come in bunches they really mean anything.

But I still think that the goal should be that every flag gets reviewed. People don't flag just for fun (>90% helpful rate usually). And in order to encourage people doing it, the part of reviewed flags should not be too low. There certainly is a critical ratio where people will stop flagging (if they would be aware of it). (Which itself then would drive up the reviewed fraction ratio again, so kind of self-stabilizing.)