# Re-flag aged away flags with the same flag reason

Tags: discussion, flags, age

I understand the need to age away flags but after my flags are aged away I can't re-flag them with the same reason.

[image]

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2349270/2246380) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15118045/2246380) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13381753/2246380) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5820740/2246380) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28529026/2246380) [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11792529/2246380) [which](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3739474/2246380) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776754/2246380) [aged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9955039/2246380) [away](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12228389/2246380).

Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/2246380) suggests that I could downvote, edit or re-flag them. I think that editing and downvoting will keep the posts open instead of closing them which is my motive of raising the flag in the first place. If I can't re-flag the post for the same reason I flagged it earlier and end up with flagging them with another reason I am sure my flag will get declined they will stay open attracting answers from new users on posts off-topic for Stack Overflow.

I want to know how to re-flag an aged away flag with the same reason.

Comment: ["Not going to try to re-write history...; this would go into effect for current and future votes."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting#comment816968_250223) :(

Comment: @gnat I didn't understand what shog9 meant by that comment. Does it mean that this feature request will be declined?

Comment: @Sri I understand it to mean that flags aged away immediately when this went into effect won't be re-flaggable, but any flags cast after the feature that age away will be. But of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: @gnat Your comment is a reference to a vague comment answering an unclear question; something that's prone to misinterpretation. In particular, since closeflags never aged until the new policy was introduced, there is no rewriting to be done about them. Those that were in the system ("current") have the new aging policy applied to them. They aged immediately (if they were old), and the 14 day count began.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I think you have a point. As an example, [my testing](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21892619#21892619) of how it works turned out differently than I expected given comment I quoted

Comment: @gnat Also, below on this page: "VERY old votes - those that aged away 3+ years ago - may not be tracked properly (they may be permanently locked)." From where I infer [not logically, but by common language usage] that the ones not that old are not locked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the bottom of the [post announcing these changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/259867):

> Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days. That is, 14 days [...]  after your vote has aged away, you're free to cast the same vote again.

I emphasize that these 14 days are counted *after the vote/flag aged away* (which itself  takes 14 days or more).

Hovering over the "aged away" text will tell you when the aging happened, so you will know how long you have to wait before reflagging.

---

Of course, you can decide to do something else instead, like [complaining in a chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3115243#3115243) about the aged flag...

Comment: thanks for the answer and the suggestion about chat rooms +1

Comment: This is correct. Also note that VERY old votes - those that aged away 3+ years ago - may not be tracked properly (they may be permanently locked).

Comment: So, wait, how is the aging date set for existing flags when this change went live? 14 days after initial flagging, or the date the scripts ran?

Comment: @NathanTuggy The date the scripts ran. All the aged closeflags in existence have aged within the last couple of days.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: That's what I thought, but Shog9's comment seemed to indicate the system thought differently.

Comment: @NathanTuggy His comment is about closevotes; those had [different] aging policies applied to them for a long time.