# Re-flag orientation after flags aging away

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderation, banning

Several of my flags aged aways these days.

I know we should re-flag questions when we think that's appropriate. So I went forward and restarted the tedious flagging process. As I never did that before (flags never get to the point of ageing away at CrossValidated, for example), I was surprised I couldn't actualy reflag (as in the option is greyed out). So I flagged the questions for moderation attention. **Two got accepted**, four rejected:

> "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention"

Great. Insta-ban from flagging.

I now (edit: to clarify, I mean after being banned, I didn't know it beforehand and no one would know it presumably since it's not made clear to the user) know re-flagging is only allowed after 14 days: [Re-flag aged away flags with the same flag reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287317/re-flag-aged-away-flags-with-the-same-flag-reason).

As I made explicit I was only asking for moderation intervention because the system didn't allow me to reflag, I expected at least some orientation, <s>and "disputed" instead of "declined</s>" (Servy corrected me, through *moderation intervention* this would be impossible).

Now I'm totally not wasting my time with some of these flags as I know they will age away anyway, and I won't bother to look 14 days after the event, that is, ~1 month after I flagged them, to reflag them.

I think reflagging as a desirable behavior is well established on meta, so:

### The questions for discussion are

- Could the moderation make it clearer reflagging should wait some time?
- Moderation intervention is out of the question here?

Comment: Dontflaganagedawayflag.com flag it, forget about it, and move forward!! This is the desired behavior here on SO (from my experience) and don't bother too much about getting that question closed at any cost!!

Answer (score 11):

IMO, **moderation should make clear the process of re-flagging**. Period.

This whole thing (including the insta-ban) is just a big "don't waste your time to improve the site" for me. I'm completely not wasting my time with these anymore, and I think many resonate this feeling, flagging only the ones that will not age away.

**The time to re-flag must be changed depending on the type of the flag raised**, I (and presumable no one that values their precious time) won't bother to re-check flags **1 month** after raising a flag.

As I'm no way associated with StackExchange, this is only my own opinion.

---

Regarding the answer by [@Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy), no, the moderation didn't make clear. There are several views in meta (both here and on meta.SE itself) putting forward re-flagging as a good option after raised flags age away. **Nowhere it says one would have to wait an arbitrary amount of days to do what everyone advises one to do**. This should be made clear: I went to re-flag as everyone tells me to do, system doesn't allow me to do it, I use the only other apparent alternative (*i.e.* moderation intervention) and for trying to help the site I'm awarded an insta-ban. Great incentive!

---

Adressing other points by @Servy, to make clear to other posters what I mean with all this:

> *"You've provided posts that say you're welcome to re-flag a post after the flag ages away if you would like to, when you are again able to"*.

People didn't mention this part, nor the system (how would I magically been able to know that only after an arbitrary amount of 14 days I would be able to contribute to keep the site clean for free?).

> *"You have not in any way indicated that it's a good thing to always go to every single post that has an aged flag and immediately re-flag it"*.

Neither did I intend to do.

> *"In fact, Shog's post rather contradicts that opinion of yours"*.

No, it doesn't.

> *"You're acting like you've been wronged because you struggled to immediately re-flag every single post the second it aged away"*.

How horrible of my part I feel like I shouldn't be punished for trying to help with the moderation of this site for free.

> *" That's very strongly indicating that you feel it's essential to re-flag every flag that ages away"*

For me? It certainly is, as you know, I don't work for StackExchange, nor do I have to time to keep revisiting posts months after flagging them. But I never implied I think everyone is required to do that. It's now basically implied it's bad to actually try to re-flag bad content, and I'm refraining from doing it, to the detriment of the site content, from now on.

Comment: "Everyone" isn't telling you that it's your imperative to always re-flag every flag that ages away as soon as  you can.  I asked you to provide even *one* example of this and  you failed to provide one.  Again, if the site just wanted everyone to always re-cast every flag that ages out as soon as possible *they wouldn't age the flag away in the first place*.  Given that the system is also going out of its way to *stop* you from re-casting the flag immediately, that should be telling you something.  You tried to subvert the system by using inappropriate flags.  You've faced the consequences.

Comment: @Servy you're saying this as if I owe something to StackExchange regarding the moderation of their own site. I do not. I'm just trying to help to keep the site clean. For trying to help I'm punished. "Everyone" is obviously a hyperbole, as I said "there are several views in meta (both here and on meta.SE itself) putting forward re-flagging as a good option after raised flags age away". You can read it clearly, "good option", not "requirement". You are picking the wording of the post instead of addressing the discussion Servy.

Comment: Where did I say you owed anything?  *You're* the one saying you owe something.  All I've ever said is that you shouldn't be abusing the flagging system by flagging posts in an inappropriate manner just because the system is going out of its way to prevent you from casting the flag you *want* to cast.  You're not *obligated* to use the system, but if you choose to, you need to use it appropriately.  Again, you've found a post that says you're *welcome* to reflag a post after a while; that you *can* in no way obligates you to, as you claim.

Comment: @Servy the unadressed question still is "Could the moderation make it clearer reflagging should wait some time?". Because as it's now it's completely unclear to new users they have to wait an arbitrary amount of days to cast flags again to try to improve the site.

Comment: I'd say that stopping them from being able to cast the flag during that time is a pretty strong signal that they shouldn't be re-casting that flag during that time.  You don't really need to go out of your way to inform people that they can't do something.

Comment: @Servy the prompt doesn't tell you there's a time to wait, it only tells you already flagged it. Combining it with the much proliferated idea that reflagging is allowed (and even encouraged), how do you expect an user to magically figure it out?

Comment: If by "much proliferated", do you mean, one meta post that *also* specifically mentions that you cannot do so immediately, because that's not "much proliferated".

Comment: @Servy I looked here Servy: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/2874779

"That doesn't necessarily mean they were wrong, just that there were other priorities. The recent change that marks them as "aged" means they won't sit forever in limbo - you now know they haven't been acted on, and are free to take alternate action (voting, editing, **re-flagging**) if you see it as necessary to maintain the quality of the site." (83 upvotes).

Comment: Yes.  What's your point?  How is that anything but consistent with everything that I've been saying?  Your suggestion that people should always be re-flagging every single post that ages away, immediately, no matter what, and that failing to do so is a problem, is contrary to that post, and my statement that you're we-come to re-flag when you're able to do so is acceptable, but by no means expected or required of you, is entirely in line with that.  You keep quoting posts that support my position and contradict yours.

Comment: That's a strawman @Servy, I didn't claim re-flagging is *required* as you are repeating continuously, I said it's often suggested as a good option, and I provided posts corroborating that view. You are conflating what I said with what you would have liked I had said for the sake of debating.

Comment: You've provided posts that say you're *welcome* to re-flag a post after the flag ages away if you would like to, when you are again able to.  You have not in any way indicated that it's a good thing to always go to every single post that has an aged flag and immediately re-flag it.  In fact, Shog's post rather contradicts that opinion of yours.  You're acting like you've been *wronged* because you struggled to immediately re-flag every single post the second it aged away.

Comment: Yes, technically you didn't *say* that you were required to re-flag the posts, you've simply acted as though you felt you were required to.  You created a meta post to complain about what a horrible thing it's going to be that you won't be able to immediately re-flag every flag that you've cast that ages away the very instant that you're able to, and how it's going to be such a loss that you'll have failed to re-flag some number of flags that have aged away.  That's *very* strongly indicating that you feel it's essential to re-flag every flag that ages away.

Comment: *"Yes, technically you didn't say that you were required to re-flag the posts, you've simply acted as though you felt you were required to"*. 

**Technically**, @Servy, you made this up.

Comment: No, I did not.  But since  you're apparently *now* stating that you *realize* that it's not important to immediately re-flag flags when they age away, you realize that the entire problem that you're bringing up in your quesiton, that it's not easy to be to go through and re-flag all flags as soon as you're able to do so, isn't actually a problem, it's by design.  Or are you saying that you knew that the behavior you're indicating was too hard for you to do wasn't desirable and that you proposed changing it anyway?

Comment: `People didn't mention this part` But..they did.  You've so far provided two links.  One specifically about the re-flagging of aged votes, that specifically mentions the 14 days, and one that did not.  So saying, "people didn't mention it" isn't true.  `Neither did I intend to do.`  You're complaining about the fact that you can't, and how that's bad.  That's functionally saying you think it's important to do it.  `No, it doesn't.` But it does.  Saying it doesn't doesn't change that.

Comment: `How horrible of my part I feel like I shouldn't be punished`  You're "punishment" was the inability to cast flags for a few days, as a result of you casting numerous inappropriate flags.  In what way is that not an appropriate reaction?  `For me? It certainly is,` Odd, given how many times you've tried to say you *don't* think it's essential for you to do this.  Anyway, what you know is that it's bad to cast tons of mod flags when your flags age out, and if you want to re-flag every aged flag you *can*, but it'll be inconvenient to do so, and it's not important that you do so.

Comment: But hey, thanks for freely admitting that I didn't make up the fact that you clearly feel that it's essential for you to re-flag all of your aged flags, and that your assertion that I "made it up" was just flat wrong, and you knew it.  That cleans that up nicely.

Comment: @Servy I see in Shog's post there is a comment at the bottom (not upvoted) mentioning 14 days. Am I supposed to read every comment in every meta thread now? This thread is about how **moderation should make this clear**. And going by the votes people seem to agree with me: **moderation doesn't do this process clear at all**. Now please, agree to disagree.

Comment: So you just completely skipped the statement, "Note that there's a 14-day waiting period for re-raising aged flags, so you might have to wait a little bit." that is in its own paragraph in the post itself?

Comment: @Servy *"that it's not easy to be to go through and re-flag all flags as soon as you're able to do so, isn't actually a problem, it's by design"*
The thread isn't about this at all, it appears you didn't read it. It's about how it's a really **unclear** process, and this punishes users that are trying to actually improve the site. The moderation is currently lacking much in documenting this. It's basically a big "don't try to improve bad content" banner being waved at the users faces.

Comment: @Servy where's it here Servy? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away/287211#287211

Comment: Like I said, you mentioned two posts, one brought it up, one didn't.

Comment: @Servy I had to go out of my way to search the reason I was banned Servy, that's the reason I found the other posts. Though I was basing myself on the point of this one post specifically (83+). Do you think I have free time to keep reading everything here on meta, or to keep casting flags all the time? I'll repeat myself, **moderation didn't make this clear at all**, this is the sole reason for all this (and this question for the matter), and you still haven't addressed this.

Comment: You weren't banned from the site.  You were banned from casting new flags, because you cast inappropriate flags when the system *vary clearly told you* that you couldn't cast the flag that you wanted to cast, because you had already cast such a flag.  Yes, the system didn't tell you that that was only a 14 day limitation.  Had you never learned this, you may never have re-cast the flag again later, and instead directed your attention to finding different problematic posts to flag, if you wanted to spend time aiding in moderation.

Answer (score -1):

Flags aren't disputed when a moderator looks at the flag and determines that it was not an appropriate flag.  Flags are disputed when they don't end up being sent to a moderator for some reason.  (Some flags, such as VLQ, are disputed if the post is edited, other flags will be disputed if a review queue, being used by non-moderator users, determines that the flag wasn't merited.)  Your flags were declined because it's not appropriate to use a moderator flag to indicate that another type of flag you cast had aged out.  This is as expected.

> Perhaps the moderation could make it clearer reflagging should wait some time?

Well you've *already* made it clear that you knew you had to wait before re-flagging the content.  Apparently we *already did* make it sufficiently clear.  That you knew what you needed to do and simply choose not to isn't a failure of the system to inform you what the appropriate course(s) of action are.

Comment: I didn't say that, did I? I "now I know" means I looked after the fact and learned, after being insta-banned, that reflagging should wait 14 days.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure So you assumed that when the system went out of its way to stop you from casting a flag it did so because it wanted you to use a bunch of custom moderator flags to notify them that your previous flags all aged out?  Why would they do that?

Comment: Meta makes clear aged away flags should be reflagged, it's all over the place. Nowhere it said I should have to wait 2 weeks to do it.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure If they just wanted you to re-flag every aged flag *the flag wouldn't age away in the first place*.  You're *allowed* to re-flag a post after 2 weeks.  That's not the same thing.

Comment: "Flags are disputed when they..." aren't unanimously solved. Flags are marked as disputed when the review queues don't reach a consensus (ie both recommend deletion and looks ok) about a post.

Comment: "If they just wanted you to re-flag every aged flag the flag wouldn't age away in the first place. You're allowed to re-flag a post after 2 weeks. That's not the same thing", really? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289728/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-a-flag-that-has-aged-away : "But that's a lot of work for you to go through, so in the future just re-flag it: the question will go up for review again, and perhaps catch a bit more attention this time." (Shog9)

Comment: Also this question isn't about what should I have done, instead this is about what moderation could do (i.e. inform better the users).

Comment: @Braiam If the review queue takes the action the flag suggests the flag is not disputed, even if the chosen action isn't unanimous.  The flag is only disputed if the action the flag indicates should take place is an action the queue chooses to not take.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure I don't see anywhere in that post it saying that users should always re-flag every single flag of theirs that ages away.  It merely says that you can re-flag it, eventually, if you want to.

Comment: Err, no. ["When you flag an answer as NAA or VLQ and the post doesn't result in deletion **but someone recommended deletion**, the flag is disputed."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141400/213575) It would end declined if everyone said "looks ok".

Comment: @Braiam I was listing of the circumstances in which disputed is used, not all of the possible results of a given review action.  The only way for a flag to be disputed is if a mod doesn't see it, but rather through some other type of invalidation of the flag.  That doesn't mean that *every* type of invalidation of a flag necessarily results in disputing the flag.

Comment: Servy, then how come 2 flags got accepted?

Comment: Then don't spread misinformation, or better, don't mention disputed at all if that's not the point of your answer and link instead http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/213575

Comment: @Braiam It's not misinformation, I explained the aspect of disputed flags that's relevant to this specific question, without providing a complete description of all possible flag states and every circumstance in which they can come up.  I explained why these flags were declined, rather than disputed, and gave a clearly non-exhaustive list of examples of situations where a flag would *actually* be disputed.  Leaving it out would be failing to answer the question.  Explaining everything about every possible resolution to any flag would be going beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure You'd have to ask the mod that accepted them.

Comment: Okay Servy, but this isn't the point of the question anyways.

Comment: @Servy as a long-term lurker and occasional answerer on SO and throughout SE, I have steered clear of doing more than simply ignoring content that I suspect should be flagged because of the opacity of the process. Reading this question, discussion, and your answer reinforces my conclusion that taking advice from meta (such as the OPs linked advice from a diamond mod) about how and when to flag is too frustrating and unclear. The only predictable results seem to be punishment for those who care about site content and the excuse that the punishments are justified because too few people care.

Comment: @newcoder You think, "flag for the appropriate reason if it's available, just don't use a completely inappropriate flag reason because the one you want to use was intentionally disabled" is too complex for you?  And regardless, the only "punishment" that took place was an inability to cast new flags for a few days, nothing more.

Comment: @Servy You're missing the point. I think the definition of "completely inappropriate flag reason" is too unclear in the interface, documentation, and meta discussion, which is the point of this question. The linked advice "so in the future just re-flag it: the question will go up for review again, and perhaps catch a bit more attention this time" is at odds with the attitude that aged-away flags should not be re-raised. What do those who care about the site's quality have to lose from making the re-flagging limitations and options clearer in the UI?

Comment: @newcoder So you think people need to be specifically told that when a given flag reason is explicitly disabled, with a reason why, that they shouldn't flag the post for a different reason, that *isn't* merited given whatever problem the flagger has found?  I would think that would be pretty self-evident.  `the attitude that aged-away flags should not be re-raised`  A flag *cannot* be re-raised immediately.  It's perfectly fine to re-raise it after a while when it is re-enabled, so this "attitude" isn't really the case...

Comment: @Servy I find it entertaining that your argument for leaving the UI and documentation as they are hinges around the assumption that everyone encountering it can be reasonably expected to arrive at the same conclusions you do, when most of the comment thread between yourself and the OP consists of you mis-interpreting a question that at least 9 other people (by net votes) found perfectly clear. Again, what does the site have to lose by including a text like "if this question is still here and requires [flag type] 14 days from now, you may re-flag?"

Comment: @newcoder What about the question did I misinterpret?  I disagreed with many of his assertions.  I never said his question was unclear.  I also note that you didn't actually answer my question.  You say you're entertained that I would make an assumption that someone could come to that conclusion, and not indicated why you feel that assumption wouldn't hold.  Why, if at all, do you feel it's reasonable to expect people to cast inappropriate flags when the system tells them they can't use the flag they want to cast?

Comment: @Servy You answered the OPs surprise that the flags were not disputed, which is your only content I see on this question for which you have cited a consistent source. However, declining flags was an aside in the original question, and nowhere did the OP ask what they should have done. OP asked "Could the moderation make it clearer reflagging should wait some time? Moderation intervention is out of the question here?" and you assert that flagging for moderation intervention IS inappropriate and are silent on the first point. The onus is on you to defend your interpretation.

Comment: Evidence to support my point: Meta discussion is an inconsistent source, as previous links show and you yourself agree. Vote counts here show the preponderance of those who care about this question agree with @catastrophic-failure and I. The OPs two "helpful" mod flags in the original question stand as evidence that flagging for mod intervention when the waiting period has not expired to re-flag for the original reason is NOT ALWAYS inappropriate.

Comment: Note: We are not arguing that raising mod flags instead of re-flagging is always appropriate. OP is asking how could the distinction between appropriate and inappropriate actions be clarified. Further, there is precedent on SE for encouraging users to raise a mod flag for a situation where the UI does not allow one to take the "more correct" action. I will locate a link if no one else does so first citing meta discussion *encouraging* users who cannot yet VTC to raise and explain mod flags when they encounter questions which "should be closed."

Comment: Citations of SE precedent: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions "once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now." Related situation b/c users "cannot flag a question for closing if the question has a bounty on it."      http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260606/change-close-vote-to-mod-flag-bad-questions-with-open-bounty "flagging for mod attention is an option"