# The process of flags aging away sucks

Tags: discussion, flags

Sorry for the clickbaity title - but hear me out for a second.

Many of my flags aged away. 38.2% of them to be precise. This is frustrating and demotivating. I catch myself not going through the hassle of flagging older questions as it seems unlikely anyone will look at the flag anyway. I think the system should be adjusted in some regard.

**One example:**
[This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839850/how-to-embed-a-pdf-file-in-electron) is a very obvious duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844135/how-to-view-a-pdf-in-electron-browserwindow). Accordingly I flagged it as such. Three times as you can see here:

[image]

Most people arriving at the flagged question would have benefited from having a link to the other one but every duplicate-flag aged away. I actually thought about just copy-pasting the answer but that is not allowed.

Now I do know that the aging-away-process is relevant and has a purpose. However I think we can improve upon it. **Here are some ideas:**

- Notify the user if a flag aged away (I would generally appreciate better feedback regarding the quality/outcome of flags and if one would be notified about one aging away they could go back, look at the question, decide if it is still valid and potentially re-flag)
- Reduce/remove the time limit for a re-flag (If one takes the time to go through the aged-away flags to re-evaluate the questions - why can't they re-flag if they think it is necessary? For each of the aged-away flags from the example above I had to wait 14 days(!) until I could re-flag)
- Give each/some users a very limited amount of high-priority flags which can't age away
- Make re-flags impossible to age away (So if one waits 14 days to re-flag a question it can't age away again. This would only apply if the flag is the same. I think the number of re-flags is pretty low which is why I think this would be feasible without bloating the queues)

I would greatly appreciate any additional ideas!

Comment: You need to appreciate the fact that the close vote queue (where these flags are handled) is overloaded, with way more work coming in than being done. The mechanism of aging away keeps the queue from growing indefinitely, which would be bad for everyone. Even making a fraction not age away would probably result in the overloaded queue becoming substantially larger

Comment: The specific question has been hammered now

Comment: As already mentioned, the CV queue is big. We were struggling to keep it down even during [the 3 vote experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-days-ended?cb=1). Close flags aging away is an unfortunate side-effect of the queue size, and it won't get better at 5 votes to close. I wouldn't focus too much on the aging away process, but rather fix the problem that causes flags to age away in the first place.

Comment: I totally sympathize with this. Working mainly in a low-traffic tag I experience this all too often! I don't have the "roomba" (automatic clean-up) rules memorized... Some questions with no answers or votes will get automatically removed, so flags aging way on those is not so much an issue. There are things, however, that would benefit from not being allowed to fall into limbo...

Comment: The roomba rules are listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba - the thing with roomba is that a single answer stops roomba if the question isn't closed (and the closure reason isn't duplicate). Questions with answers need to be closed to roomba, and the answers can't be upvoted. Questions need to be closed to be deleted manually. Generally, cleanup of questions requires closing, so flags aging away is a big deal. On low-volume tags, I guess there's fewer people who answer too, so the chance a misguided user shows up and answers is lower than on high-volume tags?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386562/6296561

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336171/7910454

Comment: @Zoe I see that the CV queue is very full. However, I don't see how dismissing (seemingly) random flags is a solution. If we were to dismiss every flag, there would be no CV queue at all but SO would be a much worser place.

Comment: @leonheess they're not dismissed. There's no one to blame for aged away flags, but they age away because the system determines the flag is too old. It does lead to problems, like hiding questions that should be closed, or wasting reviews and/or close votes, but it's because the underlaying system isn't designed to handle the volume of questions SO gets every day.

Comment: @Zoe I would argue that they are dismissed. Not manually but by a system which was told when to dismiss them. And I think this system or its communication to the user should be improved. I'm unsure what you point is. Do you think the current system is ideal and shouldn't be changed or do you agree that it should be changed but there are more important things (improving CV queues etc.) rn?

Comment: My point is that flags aging away isn't a problem if the questions in the CV queue are cleared away fast enough to prevent flags from lasting long enough to start aging away. No backlog means very little ends up aging away (where the stuff that does age away are cases where no one is sure how to deal with it, and no one clicks anything but skip). Fixing how flags age away just shifts the problem - the real problem is what causes the flags to stay unhandled for long enough for them to age away. No parts of the system are optimal at the moment, but this is just a consequence of the main problem,

Comment: and not a "full" problem on its own. Make the CV queue more efficient, reduce the size, fewer flags age away. Don't do anything about the CV queue, flags remain pending for half an eternity, while nothing in reality changes. Close votes are also subject to aging away (but not nearly as visible as flags aging away).

Comment: @Zoe I see your point now...

Comment: @Zoe I don't have an overview what is happening regarding that CV-queue problem - does it make sense to make changes regarding it's symptoms or will it be solved in the foreseeable future?

Comment: This is the current status: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387674/6296561 - as for fixes, SE ran the 3 CV experiment as a potential partial fix. There's still a lot more that needs to be done, but we have no idea what's planned, aside the 3cv experiment

Comment: @Zoe So what about, let's say, the last option (keep re-flags infinitely) - is there a way to find out how many flags that would amount to?

Answer (score 5):

If you're concerned about "Should be closed" flags (in particular) ageing away (and also "Close Votes," if/when you have > 3,000 rep) - *and I do understand that this can be frustrating for low-traffic tags* - then you should perhaps consider joining the [SOCVR Chat Room](https://socvr.org/).

You can raise your flag (or cast your vote), then look for 'support' from other folks in that room. They're a pretty friendly lot (especially to newcomers) but they are *primarily* interested in keeping SO clean and tidy (it's called, "User-Level Moderation," but it has been known for *real* moderators to appear there, from time to time).

There are rules that should be followed (as in any chat room) and 'proper' ways to make "Close" requests, but you'll get a good introduction from the "Tour" and "FAQ" on the given link.

I would also recommend just 'lurking' in the room for a while, to get a feel for how things are done therein.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will probably do this from time to time now but I don't think this is a real solution whatsoever as it would increase the problems if applied to all users

Comment: @leonheess SOCVR is not, in itself, a solution, but it contributes. Also, the lowering of the threshold from 5 to 3 close votes has *certainly* helped the problem: back in October last year, IIRC, the "Close Vote" queue was over 7,000 long - now it's just over 3,000 - and falling.