# What causes a flag to be 'aged away'?

Tags: support, flags

I recently tried to become more active on Stack Overflow. So, I started asking and answering questions whenever I can, using my upvotes(can't downvote yet) and flagging posts as I see fit. One thing I've come to notice though is that a flag that sits for a while without being acted on can become "aged away". While I'm content that this happens, what causes it?

At first it seemed obvious; a flag that sits for a stretch of time is "aged away". But I came across a case where I have aged away flags that are newer than flags that are still pending. This is demonstrated below.

[image: aged away flag]

I have seen the "[Why were my older close flags "aged away"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away)" post and while that explains actions that can be taken on flags that have aged away, it doesn't answer my question; **When** do posts become aged away?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I did come across that post while searching for what I'm experiencing, but didn't find anything useful in regards to my own curiosity in it. I've learned that the flagged posts that become aged away can be reflagged from that post, but I'm very curious as to when it happens. More specifically, why it would happen on a newer flag while the older flags are still pending.

Comment: Meat.SE FAQ: [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as “aged away” by the system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system) However, it's not obvious to me why any of those rules apply here. If you agree that none of those aging rules apply here, I suggest you edit your title (and question body) you ask why a flag was aged away prematurely.

Comment: @apsillers, I'd not even considered this for Meta SE and didn't come across that post during my search; That's my fault, and thanks for the link. It seems like one of those rules must apply for what I'm seeing. The aged away post **does** have >= 100 views so I'm assuming it hasn't had a vote in the 4 day period, so I'd say that answers my question. If you'd like to post an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it so this question doesn't just sit here without one.

Comment: Related: [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)