# Very tiny asterisk inside flag overview

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I'm a bit confused. After i opened my flag history and saw this sentence (didn't scroll at all)

[image]

i went to my kitchen and fetched the glass cleaner to clean the tiny smudge in front of "*older flags were not recorded helpful/declined*". 
Of course it stayed on my screen so that i inspected the element and found out, that it is an asterisk.

So, normaly an asterisk never goes alone ([Wikipedia - Asterisk - Footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk)). I took a look but i didn't found the other asterisk.

[image]

So, does this asterisk make sense over there or should it be deleted?

Comment: I've seen in several places (on other sites or even product labels) where the "first" asterisk did not exist- The one in front of the "extra info" or "footnote" was really only there to draw your attention to the note. (I've noticed when I see this, I read whatever I'm looking at more carefully to try to find the first asterisk- In a number of cases, I wouldn't be surprised if that was actually a goal of only having the second asterisk.) Here, I think it's really just to give a little extra note to a bit of information you might find useful. While not common, it is a tactic that is used.

Comment: And also, if you look at it. There's not a good spot to highlight. None of the numbers above specifically correspond to flags that faded without action, so there's no obvious place to put the asterisk.

Comment: Yes, so in my mind it is just confusing there and should be removed.

Comment: I use an * to introduce a non-specific/general "footnote" item.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away

Comment: Usually it's the other way round: there is an asterisk but no explanation for it. So now I know where to look for the missing explanations. But I can get the sense of older flags in combination with milk packages.

Comment: The asterisk is a superscript, which makes it very tiny and up high. For regular footnotes, it should just be a normal asterisk.