# 7 out of my latest 10 flags "aged away"

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering if I do something wrong, as lately my flags are not getting any attention and simply "age away".

It feels like my flags were raised in vain as it seems nobody had a look at them at all, which is not really encouraging.

here is my flagging resume:

> 172   total flags
>
> 2 waiting for review
>
> 121   helpful
>
> 3 declined
>
> 14    disputed
>
> 32    aged away
>
> 2 spam flags: 1   helpful 1   disputed
>
> 1 offensive flags: 1  helpful

[image]

Comment: Some evidence or examples would be nice. What does "aged" away mean. How soon was lately. What type of flags were raised.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2275490

Comment: That isn't something that other users can see. You can only see your own flags which is why I asked for more details.

Comment: @TravisJ: added details

Comment: So the two flags in question, were they from custom flag reasons? How long ago were they flagged? In general flags will sit anywhere from 2 to 14 days depending on the type of flag and whether or not the issue flagged requires some background checking or discussion.

Comment: @TravisJ, thanks for taking your time on this, it's not really about the 2 flags waiting for review (which will age away any second), but because of the sum of 32 aged away flags. How can I edit this post, so everyone can see the flagging histroy? printscreen?

Comment: @Vickel so your question is "what am I doing wrong with flagging"?

Comment: @psubsee2003 why are so many flags aging away lately

Comment: Hm, I don't have any flags that have "aged away"

Comment: @TravisJ, well I have 32 (soon 34)... check the image I've added

Comment: Note that you can also ask this kind of question in the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: FWIW, you're probably doing something right that not enough other people are doing, at least in the tags that you frequent. Declined/disputed flags are much more indicative of you doing something wrong than flags aging away.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chances are that your flags were flags recommending closure, these flags land in the close vote review queue. The queue is generally pretty full, usually in the neighborhood of 10k, so sometimes your close-vote or flag may age away before it gets enough eyes on it to be closed.

[At the moment a close-vote, or flag recommending closure, can age away after 14 days. If you feel strongly that the post should be closed you can recast your vote, or flag, after it ages away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)

Comment: so what to do, stop flagging?

Comment: @Vickel Nope, keep flagging, flag them again if need be.

Comment: I asked the question, because I feel my efforts are in vain

Comment: ["Your flags were not a waste (..) I want to thank you for taking time to flag posts you've found problematic - it's the combined efforts of everyone like yourself, working together, that keeps Stack Overflow working day after day"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/1476885)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be helpful to you now, but once you reach 3,000 you get access to
the Close Votes queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close

by reviewing there, your votes are less likely to age away.