# Flag reviewing technique improvements

Tags: feature-request, flags

I have a lot of pending flags that have not been reviewed for more than a week!

1. What I should do with them?
2. Is there a way to improve the flag-reviewing technique? I mean that flag-reviewers should first revise old flags and then new flags to avoid the old pending flags. Maybe this, now, will make a mess, but for now moderators can review the old pending flags.

Comment: While on its face this looks like something sensible.... Do you know which flags get reviewed where, how is the volume of these queues, how many people review? I feel like the intent of your suggestion isn't bad at all. But there is a lot more factors than you seem to take in consideration here, and they can all trow monkey wrenches in your idea as they make the system a lot more complex than it may look at first glance.  As for what you can do: be patient :).

Comment: How long it takes for a flag to be handled varies depending on the type of flag, the number of moderators reviewing, the number of flags raised, the complexity of the flags, etc. It's not all that uncommon, in the past, for flags to take more than a month to be handled (or even significantly longer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your pending flags are close-vote flags. Those are not reviewed by moderators, but by normal community members. Unless I missed one, all of your non-close-vote flags (those that are reviewed by moderators) cast within the last week were handled within three hours.

The flags that you have remaining are all subject to the Close Votes review queue, which is always overloaded by the amount of content fed into it relative to the number of people who review that content. For that reason, the queue has to prioritize something, and that can lead to close vote flags of yours not being reviewed quickly or [aging out over time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away).

Comment: This is why either close flags should be disabled, the reputation requirement to flag for closure should be increased, or close flags should go to a different queue than close votes.

Comment: @TinyGiant The last option is unnecessary.  You only need to have the queue prioritize questions with more close votes on them.  Putting only-flagged questions at the back of the line is probably better than putting them in a different queue.

Comment: @Servy I dont know about that. Close flags are supposed to be partially a learning tool for flaggers, but the close vote queue does a pretty poor job of that.  ~90% of my close flags aged away.

Comment: @TinyGiant Getting a bunch of people to cast a bunch of close votes that are just going to age away instead isn't better.  And *lots* of close votes are already aging away, so it's not even like they're being taught unrealistic expectations for what close voting is like.  But sure, if we find that the flags aren't useful *at all*, by all means, have people stop casting them.  But taking reviewer attention away from actually closing questions to just teach flaggers what to do isn't useful.