# Could a flag be revoked?

Tags: support

In case you flag for wrong reason or something similar. What should you do?

Flag again for moderator attention?

And in the same context:

Is there a way to revoke or withdraw your own *flag action*<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1. Besides clicking *go back* arrow of the browser.</sup>

Comment: Once you've submitted a flag - you can't retract it. I remember asking on MSE years ago about this and the general advice was to "just not worry about it" - mistakes happen... (I was really concerned about flagging something as spam by mistake and was "oh my gawd - full panic stations - I need to let someone know I didn't mean to click that one!")

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should

Comment: Also related: [Add ability to cancel flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags)

Answer (score 4):

Flags are permanent (as Jon said in the comments) - there's no mechanism for retraction. Mistakes happen and, unlike almost everything else on this site, this particular kind of mistake is permanent.

The good news is that it's unlikely a moderator will take action on a meritless flag. (Unlikely, [but not impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).) The moderators likely *will* take whatever action is appropriate, though, unless it's something non-obvious. For example, if you flag something as spam when you should have used NAA, the spam flag will be declined, but the answer will probably be deleted anyway. On the other hand and to give a contrary example, if you flag something as NAA when you really should have used a custom flag to point out robo-reviewing, the mods probably won't catch that based solely on your flag.

The bad news is that your flag will get declined. If you're generally an accurate flagger, the only harm is to your pride. Many of my own declined flags were declined because I was in a hurry and clicked the wrong reason. It's frustrating, but it happens. Life goes on.

Comment: Just made a mistaken flag but reading your answer Ed has helped me feel a little better.  Ta :)