# The action I recommended was taken, but my flag is still pending

Tags: support, flags, migration

I commented on and flagged a question that was off-topic, and the poster took my advice and reposted the question in a different community. (Hooray! The system works!)

Now what's itching in the back of my brain is the fact that my flag for moderator attention (I wanted the post migrated to the recommended community) is no longer necessary. It's still marked as pending, and the [feature request to be able to cancel flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags) has been in limbo for two years.

We all like to feel like we're making a difference, so I tried to find out what qualifies a flag as "helpful." The answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags) says:

> Helpful means a [Moderator] specifically marked the flag as helpful, or the action that you were suggesting through a flag was taken by the community.

This is a little ambiguous. Is there a remote chance that my flag will ever be marked as helpful, since no moderator intervention is required at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if the action you flagged for has been performed in the meantime, we'll mark the flag as "helpful" and move on.

In this case, the action you requested hadn't quite been taken, since all they did was re-post the question. The original still existed here on Stack Overflow, and it had a good answer. There were more good answers on the Code Review re-post, so I migrated the question and asked the moderators there to merge the two in order to put all the answers in one place.

The few cases where we'll decline flags like this are on actions that don't require our intervention. These include using flags in place of standard close votes, flags asking us to close or delete something that's already closed, etc. If it's something the community couldn't act on (in this case, migration to a site not on the list), but a moderator or someone else took care of it, we recognize that you had the right intent.

Comment: I suppose my mistake was both suggesting that the user repost their question and asking moderators to migrate it. Thank you for the insight!