# Editing the flag of a reviewed question after flagging

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Sometimes when we are reviewing questions (specially `triage`), there are human errors like clicking `RequiresEditing` instead of `Unsalvagable`. Is there anyway to go back and change the flag ? Or should this be developed except for the random test questions ?

Comment: Spend more time on each review and this shouldn't be an issue. it's not a race.

Comment: yeah I do, But in some cases (rarely) mistakenly click requiredEditing instead of unsalvagable. There is no option to go back and mark it as unsalvagable

Comment: There is no way, no. Take your time and pay attention to where you click, go slowly.... it shouldn't happen THAT often. I do reviews on the bus on a phone UI and it doesn't happen. I can't imagine you cannot be at least as careful with a mouse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ability to cancel flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags)

Comment: @user7294900 not a dupe. This question the OP has the role of the reviewer. While your linked question, it's about the initial flagger that made the post to be in triage in the first place; retraction of flags is already possible.

Comment: yes, I retract the flag immediately